# Should limitstart=0 should be 301 redirected or have canonical tag to it

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, canonical-url, pagination

i have multiple categories with pagination. wherein limitstart=0 are there and is similar like category home page

Wondering, should a 301 redirect through htaccess is advisable **or** shall i apply canonical tag to it

Second, below is the htaccess code for it. Need comments, is the regex ok

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)&limitstart=0$ [NC]
 RewriteRule (.*) /$1?%1&%2 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what canonical URLs are for. In the example Google uses when they introduced them they showed a page where the content was the same but the sort order of a table was different. So pick the URL that will display all of the content available from the base URL and make that the canonical URL (i.e. the URL with no limit).

Comment: Thanks John, but as i have checked - have hundreds of categories. Is the above htaccess code for redirection seems correct, if have to go in for 301 redirect !!